# How to minimize the response time to fetch the data from DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I need to fetch 1000 records from mongodb , how can i do this in node js?
i have tried using pagination by sending the limit to 1000 even thought it takes 25 seconds to return the response, so is there any other way to minimize the response time ?

```
exports.getAll = function(filters, sort, skip, limit, callback) {

   let query = {
       removed: false
   };
   let filter = {};
   let options = {
       sort: []
   };


   req.skip = 0;
   options.limit = 10000
   options.sort = [
       ['_id', 'desc']
   ];

   collections.findItems(query, filter, options, (err, result) => {

       if (err) {
           logger.error('db error', err);
           return callback('Something went wrong');
       }

       callback(null,result);

   });

};

exports.getAll = function getAll(req, res, next) {

   service.getAll(req.body.filters, req.body.sort, req.body.skip, req.body.limit, (err, data) => {

       if (err) {
           return next({
               status: 400,
               error: err
           });
       }

       res.json(data);

   });

};
```

Comment: Can you share `findItems` method as well, It will also help a lot ?

Comment: @FarhanTahir I had updated the code

Comment: I have added an answer below, I hope it helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486427/8674173

Comment: do you NEED mongodb? please correct me if I'm wrong but this sounds like you want performance, and mongodb is great due to it's customization, not it's performance...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using mongoose `find` in `findItems` method. `find()` returns mongoose documents with quite lot of stuff in it.

What you can do is use `find().lean()`.

With `lean()`, simple plain javascript object of data from mongodb will be returned. It will optimize the response time a lot.

But I also suggest you to read this for more query optimizations at mongodb level: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any ORM ? Like sequelize ?

What's your structure of document?

Check your mongdb logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

If your document is straight forward then you should use indexing.

If you have index then try to rebuild them.

Sorting works efficiently when you have applied indexing. Avoid sorting on server if you can,Sort data at client side.

> Because database imposes a 32MB memory limit on sorting operations

Comment: 32MB is the limit for in-memory sort on the MongoDB server. Ideally you should [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) instead of relying on in-memory sorting in either the database server or your application code.